# Is it possible for a subquery to return two values?

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery, mysql-error-1241

Is it possible for a subquery to return two values onto the outer query?
Such as:

```
SELECT 1, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*), MAX(*) FROM test_table WHERE test=123) 
FROM another_table
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If Another_Table has 20 rows, you'd get 20 rows of output containing the same data, unless the column `test` is present only in Another_Table and not in Test_Table (in which case, it is a funny way of writing the restriction (which is a fairly extreme example of 'meiosis').

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use the subquery in the `FROM` clause rather than the field list, then you can treat the output as a table and refer to the separate columns.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by that. Can you explain a bit further, please?

Comment: `SELECT A.a, A.b FROM (SELECT a, b FROM MyTable) AS A;`

Comment: @kevin Your subquery, can go as an additional table in the `FROM` clause with an alias (eg. `AS test_t`, name the fields in the subquery too), and refer to the values in the field list: `SELECT 1, test_t.count, test_t.max FROM (SELECT ...`

Comment: Only issue here is that without join criteria, this suggestion will produce a cartesian product.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Quite right, it needs restricting.  If the queries are disjoint, then it might be better as two subqueries in the field list.  OP only asked if it was "possible for a subquery to return two values onto the outer query" - answer, yes.  Suitability was not accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

You are just selecting numbers as results so couldn't you just do:

```
SELECT 1, COUNT(*), MAX(*) FROM test_table WHERE test=123
```

Comment: They're two different tables :\

Answer (score 0):

Not possible

```
mysql> select 1, (select 2, 3) from dual;
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

If you are dealing with two tables and you what the results in one line, you should preform a join.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it depends on what exactly you want to do with the data, you can join two tables using `JOIN` syntax, and one of the tables can actually be a subquery. I think that is probably what you want.

I'm not even user what your current query will do..

Documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html